# SAS sgplot step color gradient

Tags: colors, sas, cdf, step, sgplot

I want to generate a "step" plot (CDF) and I'm trying to change the line color using the dattrmap option. But color are not changing. Below is my code:

```
%MACRO ATRRMAP(fich=,var=);
proc freq data=&fich noprint;
    tables &var/nocum nopercent norow nocol out=freq&var;
    format _all_;
    where &var^=.;
run;
data test;
    set freq&var end=eof;
    call symputx("mvCAT"||strip(_N_),&var);
    if eof then call symputx("NB",_N_);
run;
data myattrmap;
    length id $20 value 3 linecolor $10 pattern 3 fillcolor $20;
    %do i=1 %to &NB;
        id='myid';
        value = &&mvCAT&i;
        linecolor=cats("grey",put(&i*5,hex2.));
        %if &i=1 or &i=5 or &i=9 %then %do;
            pattern = 1;
        %end;%else %if &i=2 or &i=6 or &i=10 %then %do;
            pattern = 15;
        %end;%else %if &i=3 or &i=7 or &i=11 %then %do;
            pattern = 2;
        %end;%else %if &i=4 or &i=8 or &i=12 %then %do;
            pattern = 8;
        %end;%else %do;
            pattern = 41;
        %end;
        fillcolor=cats("grey",put(&i*5,hex2.));
        output;
    %end;
run;
%MEND ATRRMAP;
```

The generated data look like the following:

```
id value pattern fillcolor
myid -6 1 CXbdc3c7
myid -5 2 CXbdc3c7
myid -4 8 CXbdc3c7
```

Then, I used the sgplot:

```
PROC SGPLOT DATA=cumul sganno=annotation NOBORDER dattrmap=myattrmap;
        STEP X=variable Y=percent/GROUP=newgroup attrid=myid;
        YAXIS LABEL="Cumulative percentage of patients" VALUES=(0 TO 100 BY 
             10);
        XAXIS LABEL=" " VALUES=(-4 to 4 by 0.5) ;
        KEYLEGEND /TITLE=" " LOCATION=INSIDE POSITION=BOTTOMRIGHT ACROSS=1 
              DOWN=3 NOBORDER;
RUN;
```

The data myfile used with sgplot looks like the following:

```
variable percent newgroup
-3.66   2.70    -6
-3.41   5.40    -6
-3.26   8.11    -6
-3.28   5.8     -5
-2.97   13.51   -5
```

I would like to have a grey gradient. But first, I would simply like to choose, with dattrmap, color lines on my plot. I try with fillcolor and linecolor but it did not work. I try to change the color directly in the SGPLOT statement with the datacontrastcolors option of styleattrs and it works. Does someone see what am I missing ?

Comment: Where's the macro call, with the parameters?

Comment: @Reeza Here is the attrmap macro call: '%ATRRMAP(fich=myfile,var=myvar);'

Comment: Add that and some sample data to your post and we can test it and see where it's going wrong. Data attribute maps do work. Sometimes you need to set attrpriority=none option on the ODS GRAPHICS statement though to force it to override the defaults.

Comment: Thanks @Reeza, I updated my post with some datalines. Also, I try the attrpriority option but it didn't work :/

Comment: For some reason your code converts value to a character value. Are you having that happen as well? That could be your issue.

Comment: And you currently have pattern in the code shown, not linecolor.

Comment: Oh, yes, my code converts to character value because I declared value like character in the length statement. Thanks you, I corrected but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Did you add linecolor? You don't have that either.

Comment: Yes, I add linecolor (and have now edit my code overhead :) ), still not working, I don't understand :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be the GROUP = variable that is the variable that controls the color, shape and patterns. You're grouping your variables by NEWGROUP not the values. You could create a proxy to do this though, if that's what you want. Without some more details of what you need, I'm not sure how we can help you find a work around, but this does explain why it's not working at the moment.

From documentation:

> The values of the VALUE variable are valid data group values. These values are case sensitive. The data group is assigned in the plot statement with the GROUP= option.

***Assuming*** you do want the lines different color based on the NEWGROUP here's how you can modify your code. **Note that I've simplified your code drastically and there were issues with how you're specifying color - I ignored those for now and am leaving that up to you to fix. The values are currently hard coded in the macro.** I would also recommend changing the if `_n_` portion to use the `MOD()` function since you seem to have some sort of pattern in your data. It may not work, but worth considering.

```
*create fake data;
data myfile;
    input variable percent newgroup $;
    cards;
-3.66 2.70 group1
-3.41 5.40 group1
-3.26 8.11 group1
-3.28 5.8 group2
-2.97 13.51 group2 
;;;;
run;

*macro to create attribute map;
%MACRO ATRRMAP(fich=,var=);

    proc freq data=&fich noprint;
        tables &var/nocum nopercent norow nocol out=freq&var (drop=percent);
        format _all_;
        where not missing(&var);
    run;

    data myattrmap;
        length id $20 value $20 linecolor $10 pattern 3 fillcolor $20;
        set freq&var.;
        id='myid';
        value = &var.;

        if _n_ =1 then
            linecolor = 'CXbdbdbd';
        else if _n_=2 then
            linecolor = 'CX636363';

        *linecolor=cats("grey",put(_n_*5,hex2.));
        if _n_ in (1, 5, 9) then
            pattern = 1;
        else if _n_ in (2, 6, 10) then
            pattern = 15;
        else if _n_ in (3,  7, 11) then
            pattern = 2;
        else if _n_ in ( 4, 8, 12) then
            pattern=8;
        else  pattern = 14;
        fillcolor=cats("grey",put(_n_*5,hex2.));
        output;
    run;

%MEND ATRRMAP;

*create attribute map for newgroup;
%ATRRMAP(fich=myfile, var=newgroup);

*plot graph;
PROC SGPLOT DATA=myfile NOBORDER dattrmap=myattrmap;
    STEP X=variable Y=percent/GROUP=newgroup attrid=myid;
    YAXIS LABEL="Cumulative percentage of patients" VALUES=(0 TO 100 BY 
        10);
    XAXIS LABEL=" " VALUES=(-4 to 4 by 0.5);
    KEYLEGEND /TITLE=" " LOCATION=INSIDE POSITION=BOTTOMRIGHT ACROSS=1 
        DOWN=3 NOBORDER;
RUN;
```

Methods & rules for colour scheme names are found [here](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=graphref&docsetTarget=p0edl20cvxxmm9n1i9ht3n21eict.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).

Comment: Thanks @Reeza to giver some thought to my problem. You're right, I want the lines differen color based on the NEWGROUP. I have same values in my data MYFILE and in MYATTRMAP, but it still doesn't work. I will try an another way, thanks!

Comment: The code above works though? It worked on my machine. The color codes being used were part of the problem, I assume you switched to using the Hex codes like I did as well?